# Crystal Reports Print issue in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, crystal-reports, report, activex

I have a crystal report,print Mode is set to ActiveX. When clicking on the Print button in crystal reports viewer using IE , the printer dialog appears properly. When using Firefox or Chrome it asking me to print to pdf. Is there any way to open the printer dialog with firefox and chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome removed the ability to disable print preview, but on Windows you can still disable it if you modify the application shortcut:
add --disable-print-preview to the end of the "Destination", so it read something like:

> "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   -- disable-print-preview

This will make CTRL+P default to the regular OS-specific print dialog. Ctrl+shift+P also works, for those who can remember the hotkey every time.